# How to differentiate $l_1$ norm of a transformation?

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

Assume I have a vector $c$ and a transformation $\Sigma V^T $ and I want to minimize $|\Sigma V^T c|_1$ with respect to $c$ with gradient descent.

I want to take it's derivative.

Is this the right choice? - $sign(\Sigma V^T c)\Sigma V^T$

Will the step would be? - $c_{t+1} = c_t -\alpha \cdot sign(\Sigma V^T c)\Sigma V^T$

Edit: The full objective is:

$min |Jc-y|_2^2 + \lambda|\Sigma V^Tc|_1$

Where $J=U\Sigma V^T$ and $U,V$ are two unitary matrices.

Comment: With $\operatorname{sign}(a_1,...,a_n)=(\operatorname{sign}(a_1),...,\operatorname{sign}(a_n))$? And what do you define for $\operatorname{sign}(0)$?

Comment: The vector must be constrained, otherwise set $c=0$.

Comment: yes, the sign function is applied element-wise. sign(0) is 0 since i want to change only non-zero entries. I use this norm as a regularization of another objective and I want to use gradient descent because of the nature of the solution that this method achieves, thus I don't want to use simplex. I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the vectors 
$$\eqalign{
&x\doteq\Sigma V^Tc,\quad s\doteq{\rm sign}(x) \\
&\|x\|_1\doteq s:x \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ is the Hadamard product and $(:)$ is the trace product, i.e. 
$\;A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

Write the objective function in terms of these new variables. Then calculate the (sub)gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (Jc-y):(Jc-y) + \lambda s:x \\
d\phi
 &= 2(Jc-y):(J\,dc) + \lambda s:dx \\
 &= 2(Jc-y):(J\,dc) + \lambda s:(\Sigma V^Tdx) \\
 &= \Big(2J^T(Jc-y) + \lambda V\Sigma^T s\Big):dc \\
g=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial c}
 &=  2J^T(Jc-y) + \lambda V\Sigma^T\,{\rm sign}\big(\Sigma V^Tc\big) \\
}$$
The gradient vector $g$ is a column vector (like $c$), so the gradient descent step looks like
$$c_{k+1} = c_k - \alpha_k\,g_k$$